# Monitoring Google Cloud SQL backups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have enabled automatic backups for couple of CloudSQL instances.

I have been trying to find out a way to monitor backups. I want to know if there are any errors or skipped backups mentioned in the Backups or Operations tab. If there is any, an email would be sent.

Once I saw that backup wasn't taken because I thought there wasn't data changed since last backup but there should be some notification, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to see skipped or failed backups in GCP console. However, you can check them out with the help of the `gcloud` command line tool by first listing the instance backups, using the following command:

```
gcloud sql backups list --instance [INSTANCE_NAME]
```

and then inspecting the details of each backup by running the next command:

```
gcloud sql backups describe [BACKUP_ID] --instance [INSTANCE_NAME]
```

Or you can also use the API and perform a curl:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
     -X GET \
     https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/instances/[INSTANCE_NAME]/backupRuns
```

I would normally recommend using Stackdriver Alerting for e-mail notifications, but it is not available for backup events. Also, I believe that there are no notifications for situations where data hasn’t changed and a backup is missed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I tried to run first command and it showed a list of backups but there was one missing. Every backup status was "Successful" which is not good information. I guess I just have to trust Google to perform those backups.